# jenkins error FATAL: Unable to find build script at C:\selenium tests for moveon\moveon4tests1\build.xml

Tags: selenium, jenkins, build.xml

I am using Jenkins and Ant to run my selenium tests. It works fine when I run them on my local machine. 
Now I have a Jenkins server which is on a different location and I have to run my tests on that server.
when I tried to run the tests on that server Its is failing because it couldn't find the `build.xml` file. can you please let me know how can I change the home directory path?

```
Started by user :**********
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moveon4 java tests/workspace
FATAL: Unable to find build script at C:\selenium tests for move\movetests1\build.xml
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 9):

Are you using "Invoke Ant" in your Jenkins job configuration for the build step that executes your Ant build ?  If so, the build file location is hidden away in the Advanced section - it's an annoying quirk of Jenkins.

Comment: yes I am using Invoke Ant . It is working fine in my local machine with localhost:8080. and the location of build.xml (C:\selenium tests for move\movetests1\build.xml) Now I have a different server . how can i configure that in order to locate the build.xml on my machine?

Comment: Going by the error message, your build file should be somewhere under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moveon4 java tests/workspace.  You can click the Workspace link on your Jenkins job page to track it down.

Comment: The error is quite clear that Jenkins is not able to see the build.xml file. First check the complete location of the file, and also try what Gareth_Bowles have said, I believe it will work. Also check the location of your workspace and the required file.

Comment: Mnay thanks for your reply..Finally its working it is executing the build.xml file but all my tests are failing. The tests are written on java using selenium web driver and jenkins server is running on linux.do i need to make any other configurations to make it work???

Comment: Maybe you could post some of the error messages you're getting from your tests.

Comment: [workspace] $ ant "-Dselenium=Connection failed" run   run:
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moveon4-java/workspace/testng-sequence.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] 
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] Moveon4 Tests
   [testng] Total tests run: 25, Failures: 0, Skips: 25
   [testng] Configuration Failures: 14, Skips: 14
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] 
   [testng] The tests failed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: You can debug this by logging into your Linux machine as the user that run Jenkins and going to your build's workspace directory, then run the same Ant command that is failing in Jenkins.  You probably want to post a new question here if you still need help.

Comment: hi gareth the error is   <![CDATA[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '2.23.1', revision: '17143', time: '2012-06-08 18:59:28'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-5-amd64', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: So that's a pretty clear error message that your build can't find Firefox.  Debugging that problem is outside the scope of this question.